# Django Validation error not showing on form

Tags: django, python-3.x, validation, django-forms, django-views

## I want to check the user registration.

### if the username has already been registered, give the user a validation error.

In my terminal environment, the data_user dictionary is also printed
but in my form registration, a username validation error does not work into help.html
This is the same Form. ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdIui.jpg

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class SignUpModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    family = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)

# Create your models here.
class LoginModel(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required()
def blogPostSignUpView(request):

    form = BlogPostSignUpModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        form = BlogPostSignUpModelForm()
    template_name = "help.html"
    context = {"title":"register","form":form}
    return render(request,template_name,context)
@staff_member_required
def blogPostLoginView(request):
    form = BlogPostLoginModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.save()
        
    template_name = 'help.html'
    context = {"title":"login","form":form}
    return render(request,template_name , context)
```

### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUpModel,LoginModel

#Sign UP Form
class BlogPostSignUpForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    family = forms.CharField()
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailField)
    password = forms.CharField()

class BlogPostSignUpModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUpModel
        fields = ['name','family','username','email' , 'password']
    def check_password(self, *args, **kwargs):
        uname = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        data_user = SignUpModel.objects.filter(username=uname)
        print(data_user)
        if data_user:
            if uname == data_user['username']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user has exist !!!")
        return uname


#Login Form
class BlogPostLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()

class BlogPostLoginModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LoginModel
        fields = ['username','password']
```

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
blogPostSignUpView,
blogPostLoginView
)
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/',blogPostSignUpView),
    path('login/',blogPostLoginView),
    ]
```

### help.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block username%}
{{request.user}}
{% endblock %}

{% block form %}
    <div class="container" >

       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
         <div id="first">
                      <div class="myform form ">
               <div class="logo mb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                     <h1>register</h1>
                </div>
                </div>
                            <form action="" method="post" name="login" > {% csrf_token %}
                                  <div class="form_django">
                       {{ form.as_p }}
                   </div>

                                   <button type="submit">Send</button>
                              </form>
                 </div>
            </div>
               </div>
     </div>
     </div>

{% endblock %}
```

### What am I missing?

Comment: you are instanciating the empty form in the same variable, remove this line from your views.py `form = BlogPostSignUpModelForm()`

Comment: You must not do this. Use Django's built in authentication.

Comment: This is not the reason I found the answer, Below I posted it. thank you @NalinDobhal ,

Answer (score 0):

In Django Form and Field Validation, the `clean_<fieldname>()` method is called on a form subclass – where  is replaced with the name of the form field attribute, so

## we shouldn't use any favorite method's name in `BlogPostSignUpModelForm` class.

after replacing this, project works :)

Therefore, the code should be changed accordingly.

### change forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUpModel,LoginModel

#Sign UP Form
class BlogPostSignUpForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    family = forms.CharField()
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailField)
    password = forms.CharField()

class BlogPostSignUpModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUpModel
        fields = ['name','family','username','email' , 'password']
    def clean_username(self, *args, **kwargs):
        uname = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        data_user = SignUpModel.objects.filter(username=uname)
        print(data_user)
        if data_user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("username or email has been exist !!!")
        return uname

#Login Form
class BlogPostLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()

class BlogPostLoginModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LoginModel
        fields = ['username','password']
```